# Связанные таблицы DatagGridView

Tags: sql, база-данных, visual-studio-code, datagridview, c#-8.0

Нужно заполнить связанную таблицу, которая находиться на другой форме.Заполнить ее нужно сразу после появления
код на форме Main(первая форма)

```
        private void btnContent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgBooks.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            frmContent f = new frmContent();
            f.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Выберите хотя бы одну строку", "Оглавление");
        }
    }
```

Код который должен заполнять вторую таблицу(Он бы заполнял, если бы таблицы находились на одной форме)

```
    private void FillContent()
    {
        // сформировать строку SQL-запроса
            string SqlText = "SELECT * FROM [Table]";
            int index;
            string ID_Source;
            index = dgBooks.CurrentRow.Index;
            ID_Source = dgContent[0, index].Value.ToString();

            SqlText = "SELECT * FROM [Table],[Books] WHERE (([Table].IdKey = ";
            SqlText = SqlText + ID_Source + ") AND ([Books].ID_Source = " + ID_Source + "))";

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlText, ConnStr);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "[Table]");
            dgContent.DataSource = ds.Tables["[Table]"].DefaultView;
    }
```

Comment: вставьте метод FillContent() на событие Load загрузки формы

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Comment: На эту строчку index = m.dgBooks.CurrentRow.Index;